# How to Send Email With Form data and Attachment Using Angularjs and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, forms, email

Actually I am Sending an E Mail that can process file attachments. Recently I shifted to angular, I am trying to post the form data and able to process the email, but unable to send the attachment.

The Html Form

```
<div ng-controller="ContactController" class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="submit(contactform)" name="contactform" method="post" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>
            <!-- Form Name -->
            <legend>Online Manuscript Submission</legend>
            <br>
            <!-- Select Basic -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="manuscripttype">Manuscript Type</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select ng-model="formData.manuscripttype" id="manuscripttype" name="manuscripttype" class="form-control input-md" required="">
                        <option value="Article">Article</option>
                        <option value="Communication">Communication</option>
                        <option value="Review">Review</option>
                        <option value="Technical Note">Technical Note</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <br>
              <!-- File Button -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="coverletter">Cover Letter</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="coverletter" file-input="file" name="coverletter" class="input-file" type="file" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Button (Double) -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Reset</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

And the Controller

```
app.controller('ContactController', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.result = 'hidden'
$scope.resultMessage;
$scope.formData; //formData is an object holding the name, email, subject, and message
$scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
$scope.submitted = false; //used so that form errors are shown only after the form has been submitted

$scope.submit = function(contactform) {
    console.log($scope.file);
    $scope.submitted = true;
    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
    if (contactform.$valid) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'contact-form.php',
            data: "manuscripttype=" + $scope.formData.manuscripttype +

                "&file=" + $scope.file,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.success) { //success comes from the return json object
                $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                $scope.result = 'bg-success';
            } else {
                $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                $scope.result = 'bg-danger';
            }
        });
    } else {
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
        $scope.resultMessage = 'Failed :( Please fill out all the fields.';
        $scope.result = 'bg-danger';
    }
}
 });
 app.directive("fileInput", ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
        element.bind("change", function() {
            $parse(attributes.fileInput)
                .assign(scope, element[0].files)
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
   }
 }]);
```

And the PHP

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    //Reciever Details
    $from = 'Test Mail'; 
    $to = 'myemail@email.com'; 
    $subject = 'Paper Submission ';
    $from = stripslashes($_POST['manuscripttype'])."<".stripslashes($to).">";        

    $manuscripttype = $_POST['manuscripttype'];       

    // generate a random string to be used as the boundary marker
    $mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";

    // now we'll build the message headers
    $headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
    " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    // here, we'll start the message body.
    // this is the text that will be displayed
    // in the e-mail
    $message="Paper Submission  \n
        Manuscript Type       = $manuscripttype.\n

  Uploaded Files

        Cover Letter          = Attached as Attachement with this Mail.\n         

// next, we'll build the invisible portion of the message body
    // note that we insert two dashes in front of the MIME boundary 
    // when we use it
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
    "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
    $message . "\n\n";

// now we'll process our uploaded files
    foreach($_FILES as $userfile){
    // store the file information to variables for easier access
    $tmp_name = $userfile['tmp_name'];
    $type = $userfile['type'];
    $name = $userfile['name'];
    $size = $userfile['size'];        

    // if the upload succeded, the file will exist
    if (file_exists($tmp_name)){

    // check to make sure that it is an uploaded file and not a system file
    if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)){

    // open the file for a binary read
    $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');

    // read the file content into a variable
    $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));

     // close the file
     fclose($file);

        // now we encode it and split it into acceptable length lines
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
     }

     // now we'll insert a boundary to indicate we're starting the attachment
     // we have to specify the content type, file name, and disposition as
     // an attachment, then add the file content.
     // NOTE: we don't set another boundary to indicate that the end of the 
     // file has been reached here. we only want one boundary between each file
     // we'll add the final one after the loop finishes.
     $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
        "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
        " name=\"{$name}\"\n" .
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
        " filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
     $data . "\n\n";
  }
 }        

    // here's our closing mime boundary that indicates the last of the  message
  $message.="--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
 // now we just send the message
 if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
  echo "Message Sent";
 else
    echo "Failed to send";
   } 
   ?>
```

By Using this PHP I am able to send the Attachments and form data but using the angular I am unable to post in angular. Please suggest any changes or errors that I have done.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work.  I am also trying to submit a form with a few fields and an attachment to a php script that will email it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use .php to send mails you need some sort of backend service that can interprete php files, some frameworks (for example ionic) cant do that using internal .php file, it doesnt mind if u attach file or not, it will interprete .php as a text so u cant post data, it triggers 404 not found error. but you could use mailto() for sending mails using angular.

maybe this is your case....
hope this helps you